# PHP - Deny folder access without direct link to file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating a file hosting website. I would not like people to access the directory

```
public_html/quick/files
```

unless they have a direct download link from uploading a file. How would I go about this?

For others: To rephrase, deny permission to index all the files.

Comment: do mean allow them to access the files but not browse the directories?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!! (!'s are to meet minimum text requirements

Comment: What are the download links? Do they point straight to the target file, or do they point to a script that reads the file from disk and streams it to the browser?

Comment: direct download links. the directory is protected with a .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file named `.htaccess` in `public_html` folder with this content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: With the .htaccess will not be necessary to link all the files that are in the directory?

Comment: This .htaccess file will tell the server to disable directory listing. But everything else should work fine.

Comment: I found that blocking the directory the file of the same block also.

Comment: Nope. With this .htaccess file, complete links, I mean links that point to an existing file will work but users won't see the list of files in a directory.

Comment: For each new file you must add the htaccess? Can you post an example?

Comment: No, you just create this one line .htaccess file in your root directory and that's it. Checkout this link: https://github.com/snowy73/codeigniter-test/blob/master/.htaccess#L5 Comments are in Turkish but I think you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Creates a blank index.html file in the directories.

If thought necessary, create a redirect to an error page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=<URL_ERROR_PAGE>"></HEAD>
<BODY>
    Optional page text here.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Might be better to use .htaccess to disable directory indexes by adding `Options -Indexes`.

Comment: Yep it is! Ill delete my comment affirming this now